# Why does: alert(content[0].childNodes.length) output 7?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

Sorry for my simple question, I am new to childNodes and cannot find a related question. Why is the output of the following code equal to 7? What does it have to do with childNodes.length?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Q3(a).js"></script>
<title>Introduction to the DOM</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Introduction to the DOM</h1>
<p class="test">There are a number of reasons why the DOM is awesome.</p>
<ul>
<li id="everywhere">It can be found everywhere.</li>
<li class="test">It is easy to use.</li>
<li class="test">It can help you find what you want.</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

```
window.onload = function(){
    var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    alert(content[0].childNodes.length);
}
```

Comment: "*What does it have to do with childNodes.length?*" - that's what you are alerting?

Answer (score 2):

There are three elements that are *direct* children of the `body` element: `h1`, `p` and `ul`. The other four children represent the whitespace between and around those elements, in the form of [`Text` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text):

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var content = document.getElementById("demo");
    for (let i = 0; i < content.childNodes.length; i++) {
      console.log('' + content.childNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<h1>Introduction to the DOM</h1>
<p class="test">There are a number of reasons why the DOM is awesome.</p>
<ul>
<li id="everywhere">It can be found everywhere.</li>
<li class="test">It is easy to use.</li>
<li class="test">It can help you find what you want.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

(I had to modify the code a bit for this example to work, because the `body` itself in these snippets apparently contains more than meets the eye.)

Comment: i never thought whitespace would create a empty dom element , but why is that though ?

Comment: Not an _element_, but a _node_. `Element`s are a type of `Node` that corresponds to an HTML tag or pair of opening/closing tags. But there are other types of nodes: `Text`, `Comment` and `Attr`, to name just a few. Here's [the full list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) on MDN. Whitespace is relevant in HTML, even though in many contexts it's either ignored, or collapsed to a single space. For example, `<b>foo</b><b>bar</b>` does not render the same as `<b>foo</b> <b>bar</b>`, and the DOM has to be able to represent this difference.